# how to change the value of std::priority_queue top()?

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, constants, priority-queue

When using std::priority_queue top() it returns a constant reference. So is there a way I can both take advantage of std::priority_queue and change the value of top()?

Comment: I think the reason it's a const reference is that if you could change it, you could ruin the sorting of the priority queue. Can you not, for instance, `.pop` the value, modify it, and then `.push` it back on?

Comment: @Xymostech but I don't get a reference to the value when pop it...

Comment: Oh. Well then, make a copy from `.top()`, `.pop()`, and then `.push` it back on?

Comment: @Xymostech ......how come I didn't think of that... do you think I should just use pointer instead?

Comment: No, I think that copying and re-pushing is a fine approach.

Comment: Using a pointer definitely would be the _wrong_ thing to do.

Comment: @ildjarn so copy the top, modify then push it back is the common way people do this? Also could you briefly tell me why I shouldn't use pointers? Thanks!

Comment: @Arch1tect Yes, if the standard priority queue is used, this is is the only correct way of doing it. There are libraries that provide heaps with mutability (which can be used to implement priority queues that support mutability), in particular some of Boost's heap implementations: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/heap/concepts.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to [clarify](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15701123/why-not-modify-key-of-associative-container) one point about associative containers first, but now I'm finally able to write my answer to this question.

The basic strategy when modifying the key of an object that is part of an associave container has already been outlined in the comment from @Xymostech. You copy/retrieve the element, remove it from the container, modify it and finally re-insert it to the container.

Your question and your idea from the comment about using a pointer suggests that copying the object might be expensive, so you should also know that you *can* use a pointer to improve efficiency, but you will *still* need to apply the basic scheme from above.

Consider:

```
template< typename T >
struct deref_less
{
  typedef std::shared_ptr<T> P;
  bool operator()( const P& lhs, const P& rhs ) { return *lhs < *rhs; }
};

std::priority_queue< std::shared_ptr< MyClass >,
                     std::vector< MyClass >,
                     deref_less< MyClass > > pq;
```

now if you want to modify an object of `MyClass`, you still need

```
auto e = pq.top();
pq.pop();
e->modify( 42 );
pq.push(e);
```

but if `MyClass` is expensive to copy, using `std::shared_ptr` and a custom comparator might help to make it faster.

Comment: @Arch1tect: See also: http://open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3586.pdf (as linked by Howard Hinnant in the question I needed to clarify and that is linked in my answer above).