# Why not modify key of associative container?

Tags: c++, c++11, std, language-lawyer

I know that it's a terrible idea to change the key of an object in an associative container, but I wonder where exactly the standard forbids me to do so. Consider:

```
#include <map>
#include <memory>

struct X { int i; };

struct lt
{
  bool operator()( const std::shared_ptr< X >& lhs,
                   const std::shared_ptr< X >& rhs ) const
  {
    return lhs->i < rhs->i;
  }
};

int main()
{
  std::map< std::shared_ptr< X >, int, lt > m;
  auto x = std::make_shared< X >();
  x->i = 1;
  m.insert( std::make_pair( x, 2 ) );

  x->i = 42; // change key wrt the container!
}
```

I assume that the above *should* be illegal, but I was reading the standard for some time now and I can't find anything that actually *makes* it illegal. Where is it? Or is it hiding in a future defect report?

Comment: std::map has tree internal structure. If you modify the key, the internal structure is not correct and search won't work because you will go on the wrong path.

Comment: @Felics: That wasn't the question.

Comment: In S. Meyers's "Effective STL", there's a whole chapter on exactly this issue (see Item 22). The funny thing is that, while it's quite hard to wreck map's internal structure (since map's element type is `pair<const K, V>`) — you'll have to use some sort of aliasing for that — it is **very** easy to wreck a set and multiset, 'cause you can assign to `*it` when `it` is a (multi)set::iterator.

Comment: Informational:  See http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3586.pdf for a proposal to add a way to modify the keys in an associative in an efficient and well-defined manner.

Comment: @HowardHinnant: Thank you for the link. Thank you for the paper. Thank you for all the work to make C++ a better experience. And thank you for being you, always helpful, always constructive, always friendly!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This injects Undefined Behavior in your program if you modify the values in a way that the comparison of any two keys is different after the change according to the comparator you specified.

Per Paragraph 23.2.4/3 of the C++11 Standard ([associative.reqmts]):

> The phrase “equivalence of keys” means the equivalence relation imposed by the comparison and not the
>   `operator==` on keys. That is, two keys `k1` and `k2` are considered to be equivalent if for the comparison
>   object `comp`, `comp(k1, k2) == false && comp(k2, k1) == false`. **For any two keys `k1` and `k2` in the
>   same container, calling `comp(k1, k2)` shall always return the same value.**

Comment: +1 and accepted, but why isn't the highlighted sentence its own bullet point and instead burried behind and in the context of "equivalence of keys"? Strange.

Comment: @DanielFrey: I don't know, but it seems to me the whole Standard tends to bury relevant sentences somewhere where they're hard to spot ;)

Comment: @Nawaz: Deleting the comments... :)

Comment: @AndyProwl: More than true. In fact, I read that whole 23.2 part for more than 30 minutes before posting the question and I *still* missed it. *sigh*