# According to §12.1/4 in the C++11 Standard, the code shouldn't compile

Tags: c++, c++11, constructor, language-lawyer

**§12.1/4: and its first bullet point**

> A default constructor for a class X is a constructor of class X that
>   can be called without an argument. If
>       there is no user-declared constructor for class X, a constructor having no parameters is implicitly declared as defaulted (8.4). An
>   implicitly-declared default constructor is an inline public member of
>   its class. A defaulted default constructor for class X is defined as
>   deleted if:
>
> - X is a union-like class that has a variant member with a non-trivial default constructor,

According to this bullet point this snippet should not compile, as `struct A` is a union-like class (it contains an anonymous union) and it has a variant member, `B b;` with a non-trivial default constructor. But the [code compiles without a problem in vc++, clang++ and g++](http://rextester.com/YUZTER74836).

```
#include <iostream>

struct B { B(): i(10) {} int i; };

struct A
{
    union{ int y = 1; double x; };
    int i;
    A(int j) : i{j} {};
    B b;
    A() = default;
};

int main() {
    A a;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure `b` is a *variant* member? I cannot check right now, but that sounds suspiciously like only `y` and `x` are variant members.

Comment: The standard never requires that code not compile - it does sometimes require a diagnostic (error/warning) though.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The *variant* members are

```
union{ int y = 1; double x; };
```

and none of them has a non-trivial constructor.

This is defined in §9.5/8:

> #### 9.5 Unions [class.union]
>
> <sup>8</sup> A *union-like class* is a union or a class that has an anonymous union as a direct member. A union-like class X has a set of *variant members*. If `X` is a union its variant members are the non-static data members; otherwise, its variant members are the non-static data members of all anonymous unions that are members of `X`.

Comment: You're right. Sorry for my distraction. I'll accept your answer as soon as I'm allowed. Tks.

Comment: @user1042389: don't worry about misreading the Standard, sometimes I wonder if it is obfuscated by design (though more likely, this is just a result of its sprawling nature).

Comment: @MatthieuM. You're not alone in wondering about that, see for example [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15701123) I asked and the comments below Andy's answer. :)