# No viable overloaded '=' error with map key

Tags: c++, dictionary, operator-overloading

I'm having this error when trying to do the following

```
Rellotge nclock(request, mclock);
if (oldclock < nclock) (iteratorValue[tasknum-1])->first = nclock;
```

iteratorValue is a map dictionary and the key of the map is the same type as nclock.

> ```
>    Agenda.cc:65:70: error: no viable overloaded '='
>                 if (oldclock < nclock) (iteratorValue[tasknum-1])->first = nclock;
> ```

Comment: I asked basically the [same question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15701123/2073257) and the answers might interest you. Especially that there is a proposal to make the key modifiable, see the comment in the linked Q/A from Howard Hinnant.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The type of a element in a [`std::map<Key, T>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) dictionary is a pair as follow.

```
using value_type = std::pair<const Key, T>;
```

Notice the key is a constant element, it cannot be changed and there's a reason.

> std::map is a **sorted** associative container that contains key-value pairs with **unique keys**. Keys are sorted by using the comparison function Compare. Search, removal, and insertion operations have logarithmic complexity. Maps are usually implemented as red-black trees

Notice the highlighted points, they are the key for the reason you cannot change a key of a dictionary.

- Since it is a sorted container, using keys to order elements for faster lookup, by changing the key at any point you'd break the container because you'll end up invalidating all the sorting.
- By changing the key you could possibly *duplicate* the key elements without the knowledge of the container, which would break the unique keys guarantee.

If you need to change a key, you probably want to erase the old item off the map and insert another with the new desired key. You might want to swap the value element associated with a existing key.

Comment: You cannot *directly* change it.  You can remove the value and reinsert it with a different key.

Comment: @thelink2012 So, should I erase this item in the map and create another one with the desired key?