# How to reduce the value of C++ priority queue?

Tags: c++

Consider I have a `min priority queue` with the smallest value on the top, I hope to reduce the value on the top so that the property of the queue would still be maintained and time complexity would be `O(1)`. How to do that?

I have seen the question here [how to change the value of std::priority_queue top()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15697600/how-to-change-the-value-of-stdpriority-queue-top)

Where take the value out, modify it and push it back basically would be `O(logN)` complexity, I wonder can I make use of the property of **reducing the value** so that there is no need to push the value back again?

Comment: In what way is this not a duplicate of that?

Comment: If there was a `O(1)` way to do that, then such answer should be posted on the question you link. I am not closing as dupe, because there might be an aspect that is not yet explained in this question. Why is your question not answered by the Q&A you link?

Comment: Speaking complexity-wise, since priority queue is not a simple data structure, even if it was possible to change a priority value, it would take `O(logN)` to rebalance it. So cannot get away from the `O(logN)` complexity, it's just that with pop&push you would need to rebalance the queue twice (which doesn't change asymptotic complexity anyways)

Comment: Are you talking about how to do it with `std::priority_queue`? If the priority queue was made by yourself, it would be no issue.

Comment: You may try using a min-heap instead, and directly modifying the first element of the underlying vector. Not sure it is totally safe.

Comment: hi, I was thinking the sort of structure like min-heap with a pointer pointing to the top element that only allows reducing the value of the top element. Just wonder if it is possible to get a pointer pointing to the underlying element of the queue

Answer (score 1):

The standard priority queue doesn't support changing the keys.

What you are looking for is something similar to another data structure called [Indexed Priority Queue](https://mkhoshpa.github.io/IndexedPQ/), often used by Dijkstra algorithm.

The Indexed Prioirty queue supports 2 more methods in it's API: `increaseKey` and `decreaseKey` enabling modifying the key's itself.

The STL doesnt define indexed priority queue. You'd probably need to implement one by yourself or look for some third party implementation.

Answer (score 0):

I see the point of this question differently from others. Based on this question,

> I have a **min priority queue** with the smallest value on the top, I hope to **reduce the value on the top** so that the property of the queue would still be maintained and time complexity would be O(1).

With `std::priority_queue`, you can't. We may try a hack like `const_cast<int &>(pq.top()) = lesser_value_than_top`. It could work in some implementations, but it is NOT safe.

So, I would like to suggest building your own PQ with an array-based heap, and you can just change the top's value without log(N) work, as long as it is a value equal or less than the current top.

Comment: hi, thanks. this is exactly what I mean. Reducing the top value so that there is no need to re-heapify the queue.